# Load capacity about tomcat (which version is the best chose?)

Tags: java, tomcat, webserver

I want to make a sample project for testing the load capacity on java server,now I maybe to deploy it on Tomcat. additionally,the web server is not limited to use tomcat,the better performance one which is my really want.

the requirements are,
1,approximately 10K/second requests concurrency can be handled.
2,make a normal response result with json format for each request.

the problems are,

1,should I use cluster module on tomcat?
2,should I use task-queue ?

Answer (score 0):

Every application has it's own, unique signature and you won't be able to get an authoritative answer from anyone here regarding exact configuration for optimal performance of your particular application. Just test the various possible configurations out and pick the one that works best. Use a load-testing framework like [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/).